# Difference between a JPEG file and what is contained in a pdf's DCTDecode stream?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, jpeg

This questions is about the internals of the pdf file format and its use of the `/Filter /DCTDecode`.

Basically this Filter allows to use image data compressed similar (or identical) to what we find within a jpeg file.

Wanting impatiently include/display a jpeg image within the pdf files my little javascript generates I have attempted to simply insert the verbatim content of a jpeg file into the pdf stream object that represents the image to display.

Even though I expect, this not to be the "standard" way, it has interesstingly yielded the correct result in a bunch of viewers, among those poppler, evince, xpdf and pdf.js.

My crude/layman understanding is that a jpeg file contains a sort of file container stuff, like e.g. MAGIC FILE STRING, and header files that inform about the width and height of the image.

The question seeks the following information :

1. Is it correct to include a complete JPEG file, where pdf format would expect the stream data of a `/Filter /DCTDecode` ?
2. If it is incorrect, what are the difference between the content of a pdf's stream object for a `/DCTDecode` data and the JPGE file format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At its core sought information on the differences between the *a)* data content stored in a "JPEG file" and *b)* the data content stored within a `/Filter /DCTDecode` stream object embeded in a PDF file. Some aspects to mention are:

**JPEG Files**

First it is helpful to look a little more closely at what is actually a "JPEG file". It turns out to be less clearly defined as one might expect:

"JPEG files" come with some variety both in their file extension, as both `.jpg`/`.jpeg` are in common use, and more importantly with their file format being either [`JPEG/Exif`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF) or [`JPEG/JFIF`](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf). Even though the two formats offer some different way to store JPEG encoded image data wihtin a file they are yet very similar in that they rely both on the underlying `JPEG Interchange Format`. 
The way data is organized in this `JPEG Interchange Format` is via the use of two byte `0xFF<XX>` markers such as:

- `0xFF 0xD8` Start of Image (SOI) marker
- `0xFF 0xD9` End of Image (EOI) marker
- `0xFF 0xC4` Define Huffman Table (DHT) marker
- `0xFF 0xDB` Defined Quantization Table (DQT) marker
- `0xFF 0xDA` Start of Scan (SOS) marker
- `0xFF 0xC0` Start of Frame (SOF 0) marker
- etc...

Both `JPEG/Exif` and `JPEG/JFIF` keep those markers, and supplement a `App0` application marker `0xFF 0xE0` segment which provides some additional (yet not strictly necessary) information.

**`/Filter /DCTDecode`**

as already mentioned in another answer will at the least:

> The DCTDecode filter decodes grayscale or color image data that has
>   been encoded in the JPEG baseline format.[.....]
>   The JPEG filter implementation in Acrobat products does not support
>   features of the JPEG standard that are irrelevant to images. In
>   addition, certain choices have been made regarding reserved marker
>   codes and other optional features of the standard. For details, see
>   Adobe Technical Note #5116, Supporting the DCT Filters in PostScript
>   Level 2.

which hints on the fact that the data stored in the PDF `/Filter /DCTDecode` stream is to be `JPEG Interchange Format`, meaning it does not require the additional markers of either `JPEG/Exif` or `JPEG/JFIF`. 
However given the mechanism of providing the respective information needed for the DCTDecode prefixed/marked by the markers it the APP0 makers of either `JPEG/Exif`, `JPEG/JFIF` or even a `JPEG/Adobe` can be contained inside of the data stream, without impeeding it being correctly interpreted. Indeed it is should be possible to have wasted space in the stream data, in between marker segments, or wasted space in markers like the `0xFF 0xFE` introducing a comment section, not necessary to decode the image data.

** Baseline/Progressive/Special **

The [JPEG Interchange Format](http://www.digicamsoft.com/itu/itu-t81-1.html), which as mentioned forms both the basis of how the data is stored in "JPEG files" and wihtin the pdf's `/Filter /DCTDecode` stream object, provides different type of image encoding. 
For best compatibility, only the "baseline" encoding may be expectected to be supported in PDF viewers.

**Bottom line/Summary**

There is JIF (JPEG Interchange Format) that uses `0xFF XX` markers and which forms the basis for JPEG file formats and also is the required format of `/Filter /DCTDecode`. For best compatibilty (e.g. PDF 1.4 and earlier) only the fraction of JIF encoded image data that is "baseline" is supported, in which case it is highly likely that the content of a JPEG file will be correctly displayed when inserted direclty into the pdf's `/Filter /DCTDecode` stream, given that any APP0 marker or other markers should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF standard is specifically written so that the DCTDecode filter accepts baseline JPEG. See Section 3.3.7 of the PDF 1.7 reference (p84 in my copy):

> The DCTDecode filter decodes grayscale or color image data that has
>   been encoded in the JPEG baseline format.

There are several further notes in the spec worth reading in that same section regarding exactly what is supported.

Comment: Section 7.4.8 p. 34 https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Answer (score 0):

That's only going to work given some assumptions about the ColorSpace and the /Decode entries.

If you plan on creating/modifying PDF images you should be using a real PDF library that's going to create a real Image stream using a given filter.